# Seemingly undefined behavior with realloc in C prime generator (program posted, runnable)

Tags: c, primes, realloc

I wrote a program to find prime numbers and I use realloc() to change the size of the '*primes' block. When I put any number of bits greater than 6, I find that the first two values seem like undefined behavior and I cannot for the life of me understand why this happens (the numbers that follow are all correct). pls halp.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int int64_t;

void *safe_calloc(size_t,size_t);
void *safe_realloc(void*,size_t);

int main()
{
    printf("Prime Generator\nPlease enter the number of usable bits: ");
    int bits =0, maxNum=1, size = 6, elems = 3;

    scanf("%d",&bits);

    if(bits<1)
        exit(0);

    int i=0;
    for(; i < bits; i++)
        maxNum*=2;

    int *primes = safe_calloc(size*sizeof(int),sizeof(int));
    int *temp = safe_calloc(size*sizeof(int),sizeof(int));

    primes[0] = 1;
    primes[1] = 2;
    primes[2] = 3;

    int n = 3,j;
    for(; n < maxNum; n+=2){

        for(j = 2; j < elems; j++){

            if(n%primes[j] == 0)
                break;
            else if(j == elems-1){

            primes[elems++] = n;
            if((size-elems) < 2){

                for(i = 0; i < elems; i++)
                    printf("%d\n",primes[i]);
                printf("\n");

                size += 8;  // add 8 spaces to the prime storage array
                temp = safe_realloc(primes,size*sizeof(int));

                for(i = 0; i < elems; i++)
                    printf("%d\n",primes[i]);
                printf("\n");

                memmove(temp,primes,(size-8)*sizeof(int)); // copy over data to new array, just to be sure
                primes = temp;

                for(i = 0; i < elems; i++)
                    printf("%d\n",primes[i]);
                printf("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(bits == 1){
        printf("1");
    }
    else{
        for(i = 0; i < elems; i++)
            printf("%d\n",primes[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(temp);
    free(primes);

    return 0;
}
void *safe_calloc(size_t length,size_t dataSize){
    int *tmp;
    if ((tmp = calloc(length,dataSize)) == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: calloc failed");
        exit(0);
    }
    return tmp;
}
void *safe_realloc(void* ptr, size_t arraySize){
    int *tmp;
    if ((tmp = realloc(ptr,arraySize)) == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: realloc failed");
        exit(0);
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Note: An `exit` code of `0` is commonly used to report "no error" (that`s also what `main` returns implicitly). You should return a small positive integer instead, typically `1` if no other values are used.

Comment: 1) Not the error:  `int *primes = safe_calloc(size*sizeof(int),sizeof(int));` is probably a bit too large ... 2: `primes[0] = 1;` I don't think this a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the pointer you put into `realloc` after the call - only use the returned pointer. You also do not need to copy/`memmove`:

> The contents of the object shall remain unchanged up to the lesser of
>   the new and old sizes. If the new size of the memory object would
>   require movement of the object, the space for the previous
>   instantiation of the object is freed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `memmove` the data. `realloc` does that automatically and frees the old buffer. So the `memmove` is copying from an invalid (already freed) memory space.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, using memmove in the way you are is not correct. *[realloc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html)* preserves the current content, and adds additional memory so you can then continue with strcat or strcpy as needed.

For `realloc()` to prevent memory loss, use a temporary buf, check for NULL, then reassign to original...

```
temp = realloc(temp, 20);
if(!temp)
{
     //handle error and exit
}
buf = temp;//transfer successfully allocated memory
....
//use newly reallocated buf
```

Comment: @user3386109 - I did read them, and although you are checking for null, you are not using `realloc()` in the correct way.  `memmove()` is not necessary.  By mentioning this feature of `realloc()`, I did not want to convey it is any less important to also check return of the allocation functions in general.  _But yes, this you have done correctly!_ :)  However, the method you employ with `realloc()` in conjunction with `memmove()` will cause you problems.